# Cant change background-color for li a on hover in IE8 or IE9

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8

Ive been trying to change the background hover color of the li or anchor for the button dropdown menu on the left (It should be light grey on hover). In works in all other browsers besides IE8 and IE9.

Ive tried a good 50+ different combinations to override the red with no luck at all.

DEMO page: http://templatebase.com/lwfdev/newsub/

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post a fiddle of your problem. writing the fiddle may also help you by narrowing down the code... :hover on an anchor shouldn't be an issue...

Comment: jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bX6kp/

Comment: I have the feeling my "Narrowing down" remark didn't hit its target :-) anyway everything seems to work fine (at least the hover) here. Once again narrowing down your problem in a jsfiddle will help you to help yourself : if you can't reproduce it with a short version, then probably you're doing something wrong around your element.

Comment: I know where the color and problem is stemming FROM - but I dont know why IE8 or IE9 wont allow me to override the parent element. Ive worked on it for over an hour and tried 50+ different combinations of changing classes, styles, elements etc. Nothing else to narrow down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have repeated styles that cause conflicts.

IE is rendering these styles:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus, .dropdown-submenu:hover > a, .dropdown-submenu:focus > a {
    background-color: #BA2C26;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #C32E28, #AE2924);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

While modern browsers render these set of rules:

```
a.new-sub-a:hover, .new-sub-a a:hover {
    background-color: #EBEBEB !important;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus, .dropdown-submenu:hover > a, .dropdown-submenu:focus > a {
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Delete all the previous styles and try this consolidated version:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, does IE normally only use the first style it finds?

Comment: No. IE respects the standard CSS priority scheme
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#CSS_Priority_scheme_.28highest_to_lowest.29